# Deleted Image giving a 301

Tags: images, redirect, performance

I have images that were deleted from the site (the page and the media library) but are still being requested which can be seen in the network tab. They are redirected and take a huge amount of time making the page significantly slower. I don't know how images that no longer exist on the page and the media library can still be requested. I tried adding images with the same name but they are still redirected (probably because I set all 404's to redirect to the homepage). attached is an image with the images causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

from what I see the issue might be in the redirections you are making and how you are making them. I did some research and you can use [this](https://www.facebook.com/groups/askrubi/permalink/402550531380060/) (it is Ask Rubi group that has an article on the topic) to learn more about the redirections.

Comment: Thanks for the info it is greatly appreciated

Comment: Whilst that looks helpful, your answer would be better if you summarised the important points in the article here please (use the 'edit' link) - answers that just link to off-site articles are discouraged, sorry.